# What is the way to identify and enable logging for a library (for a class and at root level)

Tags: logback

I am using scalardb library. I want to enable logging in it.

I believe the way to enable logging is to add a line similar to `<logger name="classnameinclduingpackage" level="DEBUG" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> </logger>` in logback.xml.

I can see that Scalardb support Sl4J  and some of its classes use the logger. - https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/tree/master/src/main/java/com/scalar/db/transaction/consensuscommit

Question 1
If I want to enable logging for each class, would I have to add, for example, the following entry in logback.xml?

```
<logger name="com.scalar.db.transaction.consensuscommit.CommitHandler" level="ALL" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> </logger>
```

Adding each class like this would take a lot of time and I might miss some classes. Is there a way to provide a selector that would enable logging in all classes?

Would this work?

Is this the right way?